# rails passing "each" argument in a view to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, argument-passing

I am trying to pass arguments from a "each" loop in a view to a controller. I have a list of contracts. The 'contract' model has a 'signed' attribute which is either nil or include a datetime if the contract is signed. I want to list all the contracts in a view and either render a static partial if the contract is signed or render a link to sign the contract if it is not signed. I started by rendering the list of my contracts in a view along with the method:

```
<%@contract.each do |contract| %>
<%= @contract.reference %>
<%= show_either_static_if_signed_or_link_if_not_signed %>
```

In my helpers, I defined a dry-run method with some basic code to try for the first contract

```
def show_either_static_if_signed_or_link_if_not_signed
  @contract = Contract.find(1)
  if @contrat.signed.nil?
  render 'contracts/static_template'
  else
  render'contracts/template_with_a_link_to_sign_the_contract'
end
```

This works fine for the first contract. I want now to deploy this code for each contract in the "each" loop of my template. I tried

```
 def show_either_static_if_signed_or_link_if_not_signed(contract)
  if contrat.signed.nil?
  render 'contracts/static_template'
  else
  render'contracts/template_with_a_link_to_sign_the_contract'
end
```

But 'I get wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)' because I fail to get the 'contract' argument from the template to the controller. Could anyone provide me with the appropriate syntax to pass the argument from the "each" loop of my view to the helper method? Additional suggestions to approach this matter are also welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper method `show_either_static_if_signed_or_link_if_not_signed` is expecting 1 argument, however, you are not passing any argument while calling it from your view.

Update you view to pass required argument as follow:

```
<% @contract.each do |contract| %>
  <%= contract.reference %>
  <%= show_either_static_if_signed_or_link_if_not_signed(contract) %>
  ...
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the contract when you call the helper method...

```
<%@contract.each do |contract| %>
  <%= contract.reference %>
  <%= show_either_static_if_signed_or_link_if_not_signed(contract) %>
<% end %>
```